# add new product in shopify via php curl

Tags: php, php-curl, shopify-api

```
if(isset($_POST['add_shopify']))
{
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body_html'];
        $vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
        $type = $_POST['product_type'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $images = $_POST['images'];
        
        $product = array(
            'title'=> $title,
            'body_html' => $body,
            'vendor'=> $vendor,
            'product_type'=> $type,
            "variants"=>[[
                    "price"=> $price
                ]],
            "images" => [
                    [
                        "src"=> $images
                    ]
                ]
        );
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL," https://9e54fc.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json?access_token=*********************" );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($product));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
            }
            curl_close($curl);

            if (isset($error_msg)) {
                echo $error_msg;
            }
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($curl);
        print_r(json_decode($resp));
```

when i run this code it's return true. but when i am checking admin panel there are no product showing of that name. this code is working properly in postman api. please tell me about it what's wrong with it?

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): _"An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `['Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100']`"_ not `['Content-type' => 'text/plain',...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "product" key in the $product array, please check the below code that there is a "product" key, and inside that, all the product details are there. You have to pass the data in JSON format, but you are using http_build_query, which Shopify doesn't accept with application/json header, so please use the below code to create a product via PHP curl.

```
<?php 
    $productData = [
        "product" => [
            "title" => "Burton Custom Freestyle 151", 
            "body_html" => "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>", 
            "vendor" => "Burton", 
            "product_type" => "Snowboard", 
            "variants" => [
                [
                    "option1" => "Blue", 
                    "option2" => "155" 
                ], 
                [
                    "option1" => "Black", 
                    "option2" => "159" 
                ]
            ],
            "options" => [
                [
                    "name" => "Color", 
                    "values" => [
                        "Blue", 
                        "Black" 
                    ]
                ], 
                [
                    "name" => "Size", 
                    "values" => [
                        "155", 
                        "159" 
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => '{access_token}',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productData));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```